# NVM doesn't switch the expected Node.js version

Tags: node.js, nvm

I want to use an older version of `Node.js` in my application, and for that I have attempted to use `nvm` so that I can change the version accordingly.

Now I have three versions of `Node.js` and want to switch on specific version

> nvm use [selected version]

It is successfully executed but the version is not updated

Example of use:

[image]

Comment: try to close and reopen the cmd, then check which version is selected.

Comment: The issue is that,I have externally updated another version of `node.js`, not with `nvm`.
I removed that version and install with `nvm install` and it's working now.

Answer (score 6):

If your nvm command not updating your node version in windows, for example

Your current version is `6.11.2` and you would like to update to `8.11.3` using `nvm use 8.11.3` in windows OS then below hack will do that job.

Renamed `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to `C:\Program Files\nodejsx` it worked for me.

Credit goes to user [ituasdu](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/321#issuecomment-382396940)

Answer (score 1):

From the readme of NVM, under [important notes](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#important-notes):

> Note: nvm does not support Windows (see [#284](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/284)). Two alternatives exist, which are neither supported nor developed by us:
>
> - nvm-windows
> - nodist